# Django JSONField isnull lookup

Tags: python, json, django, postgresql, django-jsonfield

As far as I know you can't use `__isnull` lookups on django native `JSONField`. On the Internet I found [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25718) inactive issue.
As possible workaround we can of course use these hacks:

1. `model.objects.filter(field__contains={'key': None})`, which isn't so flexible since you might need to query multiple keys or whatever.
2. `model.objects.exclude(field__key=True).exclude(field__key=False)`, which is hacky and works only for boolean data.

I hope there is a better way ((c) Raymond Hettinger) of doing this. Any advises will be appreciated. For now, I will go with the first approach

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to [this](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/25718) (see the last, closing comment) the following should work     `model.objects.filter(field__key=None)` (But obviously **you should use the Django version with the fix**).

The [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#querying-jsonfield)

warn that

> Since any string could be a key in a JSON object, any lookup other
> than those listed below will be interpreted as a key lookup. No errors
> are raised. Be extra careful for typing mistakes, and always check
> your queries work as you intend.

and [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/contrib/postgres/fields/#containment-and-key-operations) they are

Comment: Seems like `field__key__isnull=True` should work as well. Finally, after all these years, this question has an answer. Thanks!

Comment: I cannot get `field__key__isnull=True` to work. Looking at the code changes in the above link, the `JSONExact` lookup was added so for me `field__key__exact=None` is working too.

Comment: Queries on JSONFields can easily be a place for bugs to hide due to the dynamic key lookup that doesn't raise errors. For example, running `model.objects.filter(field__is_null=True)` or `model.objects.filter(field__is_null=False)` mistakenly using `is_null` instead of `isnull` will always return an empty queryset with no errrors because it's looking for a key called `is_null`.

Comment: `.exclude(field__key__isnull=True)` is still not working in Django 4.1 but `__exact=None` works